# Objective-C View drawRect: change the Rect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

In my UIView's drawRect, there's a parameter rect, which is a CGRect, where would I change this rect?

I'd like to use it as a camera for a game that I am making,

such as

```
rect.origin.x = myCamera.x;
rect.origin.y = myCamera.y;
```

and then my drawing functions should draw it where the camera is placed...

How would I change the rect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't control this value. The underlying framework decides what area of the view needs to be drawn and sets the value accordingly.

You can call `setNeedsDisplayinRect:` and the framework *might* pass the rect you supply as the rect parameter to drawRect, but there are no guarantees, AFAIK.

Comment: I tried setNeedsDisplayInRect, but didn't work as expected, haha. xD

Comment: Anyway, thanks for your help, I'll select your question as the right one if there doesn't appear one of more materiality.

Comment: No probs. I'm not really sure what you are trying to achieve. If you can explain the objective in a bit more detail, then someone might be able to offer a more helpful answer.